# Model binder returns nullreference

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Roles.Count; i++)
{
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom: .5rem;">
<div class="col-lg-3"></div>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<li class="list-group-item" style="background: #f5f6f7; border: none;">
@Html.Hidden("Roles[" + i + "].id", Model.Roles[i].id)
<label for="Roles_@(i)_ischecked" class="label">
@Html.CheckBox("Roles[" + i + "].ischecked", Model.Roles[i].ischecked)
@Model.Roles[i].name
</label>
</li>
</div>
</div>
}
```

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

but the real object is referenced through these codes

```
return View(new UsersNew
{
    Roles = Database.Session.Query<Role>().Select(role => new RoleCheckbox
    {
        id = role.id,
        ischecked = false,
        name = role.name
    }).ToList()
})
```

I even referenced to my View as follow s

```
@model EtlGui.ViewModels.UsersNew
```

my ViewModel looks like this

```
 public class UsersNew
 {
 public IList<RoleCheckbox> Roles { get; set; }

 [Required,MaxLength(128)]
 public string username { get; set; }

 [Required,DataType(DataType.Password)]
 public string password { get; set; }

 [Required,MaxLength(256),DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
 public string email { get; set; }
}
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure that your query is returning any data? I would assign your roles to a local var and examine it before passing it in as the models view.

Comment: yes it returns datas

Comment: Are you sure its the `@for(..)` line that is throwing the exception (Razor does not always report the correct line number because views are compiles to cs files).

Comment: yes i'm pretty sure

Comment: i get results when i try to access a specific data from Model.Roles[0].name, when i wanted to loop through i get  object  instance not set

Comment: If you can access `Model.Roles[0].name` then it is not your `@for(..)` line of code throwing the exception. Put a breakpoint in the view and step through it

Comment: You may be trying to refer some property of your Roles object within the for loop, and that would be returning null exception. It would be helpful if you can post your complete for loop. The best option is to debug through the cshtml

Comment: i've added a for-loop with my viewModel in it